# Create OPC UA client for JAVA

Tags: java

I need to create an OPC UA client to connect to a PLC (server). I would need you to recommend me which library is better or use you and some example of Client to be able to connect and read and write variables.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have worked with two Libraries which gives SDK for OPC UA  Client and OPC  UA Server.

The first one is [Prosys](https://www.prosysopc.com/products/opc-ua-java-sdk/) and it is not open source.

And Second one is [DigitalPetri](https://github.com/eclipse/milo) which is now moved to under umbrella iot project and it is open source.

I found digital petri is much better. i recommend you to use this.
It has all SDKs for

**OPC UA Client SDK**

**OPC UA Server SDK** and

**OPC UA Stack**

see [Bench Marks](https://github.com/kevinherron/stack-bench) for OPC UA Sdks.

Comment: Can you explain why Milo/DigitalPetri is much better than Prosys other than the better performance in 2019? The Project does not seem to be as active anymore as it used to be and documentation looks thin on first glance.

I have used Prosys Java SDK in a commercial project and while not perfect, their support has been amazing (fixing bugs over my lunch break).

Comment: @ghanit how is it better other than better performance? Well, it has better performance ;) Feel free to add an answer about Prosys.